# How to multiply and return array

Tags: notepad++

i am facing problem in multiplying priceperItem and quantity and compiler is giving error like bad operator '*'

```
String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n%s\t%d\t%f\t%f","Discription","Qty","Rate","Amount",getItem_description(),getQuantity(),getPricePerItem(),getPricePerItem()*getQuantity());
```

Comment: Which language? Java?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: What this have to do with Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Either `getPricePerItem()` or `getQuantity()` (or both) most probably return datatypes where the `*` operation is not defined or allowed.